# Passing Generic type to inner class

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, pyqt, python-typing

In this code, I want to pass the type `T` to the inner class `Emitter`.

```
T = TypeVar('T')

class MySignal(Generic[T]):
    class Emitter(QtCore.QObject,Generic[T]):
        signal = Signal(T)
        def __init__(self):
            super(MySignal.Emitter, self).__init__()

    def __init__(self):
        self.emitter = MySignal.Emitter[T]()

    def emit(self,*args,**kw):
        self.emitter.signal.emit(*args,**kw)
```

It doesn't behave as expected.
If I do

```
minMaxChanged=MySignal[tuple]()
```

Then `minMaxChanged.emitter.__orig_class__.__args__[0]` looks like `T~` instead of tuple. The `minMaxChanged` class itself is as expected.

Generally, specifying `Signal(typ)` results in `typ` being the argument type expected to be passed to `emit` function.  Consequently, in this case, `Signal` is called as if it were called without args, and calling `emit` with 1 argument fails since it expects no args.

I also expected the code

```
T = TypeVar('T')

class MySignal(Generic[T]):
    class Emitter(QtCore.QObject):
        signal = Signal(T)
        def __init__(self):
            super(MySignal.Emitter, self).__init__()

    def __init__(self):
        self.emitter = MySignal.Emitter()

    def emit(self,*args,**kw):
        self.emitter.signal.emit(*args,**kw)
```

to work. However, the exact same issue remains.

*Update*

Notice that this is not a redundant complication. This class (partially brought here) is meant to wrap a Qt Signal which can only be omitted from class that is a Qt class. It meant to provide a generic signal wrapper. See [how to emit signal from a non PyQt class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461229/how-to-emit-signal-from-a-non-pyqt-class)

Trying double inheritance `MySignal(QtCore.QObject, Generic[T])` resulted in a c++ style crash.

Comment: I'm not sure if `MySignal[tuple]()` is supposed to do what you expect. Have you tried using `minMaxChanged: MySignal[tuple] = MySignal()`?

Comment: I tried now and it didn't work. Same fail.

Comment: I also don't quite understand your last example. "I expected the code... to work" – so does it work? Or if not, what do you mean by that? And what does it have to do with the generic typing?

Comment: As far as I understand you want to write a customized version of `Signal` and call it `MySignal`. Why don't you write `class MySignal(Signal): ...` and get rid of the nested class and the generic typing?

Comment: Because I have to use QObject to connect the signal. I can do this in one class, but the example I saw used the nested class. I didn't include this function.

Comment: I can solve the specific issue without nested class. However, this is a general question and there seem to be a general thing here about how generic behave that it seems that we don't understand. Can't it be like c++?

Comment: Generally no, because Python and C++ are different languages. In particular, in C++ you have to *make* code generic, while in Python due to the dynamic typing it is already generic by default. Using `Generic[T]` etc. is used to *describe* the genericity for the purpose of static type checking, but it has no effect on the runtime behavior. You might have a misconception there.

Comment: Thanks. I know this is the general concept. But it should have implications on runtime behavior as in this case. I think that Signal(int) would failed if I pass a tuple.     I asked in a wishful manner, and got my answer as trying to join the classes yield crash with 0xc000005. The class that the signal is in must  inherit directly from QObject and not from Generic I presume.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461229/how-to-emit-signal-from-a-non-pyqt-class

Comment: "I also don't quite understand your last example. "I expected the code... to work"  " - will update. Regarding your last comment about runtime, is there an elegant way to modify a class with regard to type T without Generic?  a decorator will work, but something built in.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the purpose of what you're trying to do and why? Because it seems to me that you expect to use your MySignal to work as a substitute of PyQt signal, but it won't, as a signal is bound to an instance of the class in which it's created, and you're adding it to another instance.

Comment: You should probably be using ABCs instead of `typing.Generic` — `typing.Generic` isn't really designed to have any runtime effect. This Q&A *might* help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69310382/python-init-object-of-generic-type

Comment: Thanks Alex, a good direction. @musicmante - see update.

Comment: @eyal0931 The solution is to create the `Emitter` class dynamically, using [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type): `class MySignal: def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): self._emitter = type('Emitter', (QObject,), {'signal': Signal(*args, **kwargs)})()`. You should then delegate everything to the signal by defining `def __getattr__(self, name): return getattr(self._emitter.signal, name)` and also `def __getitem__(self, args): return self._emitter.signal[args]`.

Answer (score 0):

@ekhumu suggestion indeed works. I hoped for something prettier.

```
class MySignal:
    def __init__(self,typ):
        Emitter = type('Emitter', (QtCore.QObject,), {'signal': Signal(typ)})
        self.emitter = Emitter()

    def emit(self,*args,**kw):
        self.emitter.signal.emit(*args,**kw)

    def connect(self,  slot):
        self.emitter.signal.connect(slot)
```